# To -lobjc or not to -lobjc?

Tags: objective-c, macos, gcc, linker, compilation

GCC manual says:

> *`file.m`*
>       `Objective-C source code. Note that you must link with the`*`libobjc`*
>       `library yo make an Objective-C program work.`

And:

> **`-lobjc`**
>       `You need this special case of the`**`-l`**`option in order to link an`
>       `Objective-C or Objective-C++ program.`

However, I can succesfully compile a program with simply:

```
$ cc prg.m -framework Foundation
```

Is it a linker default, when you include a framework? If so, where is it
documented? The program gets linked anyway:

```
$ otool -L a.out
a.out:
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/.../Foundation (...)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (...)
    --> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (...)
        /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.f...k/.../CoreFoundation (...)
```

Comment: have you tried compiling this on linux systems? it might be that os x does this by default.

Comment: Good catch, I haven't tried. But even the manual itself is modified, with "Apple Only" notes in many places. So I wonder (in case this is exclusive to Apple systems) why isn't it explicitly documented near these parts.

Comment: Yes it's a linker default for Apple's compilers. They're not always up-to-date in their man pages. Please file a bug report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the `Foundation` framework is already linked with `libobjc`.

So on OSX, you'll need `-lobjc` option only if you doesn't link with the `Foundation` framework (which is very rare).

Comment: Typo, it's -lobjc